# Skipping task on failure in Airflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow

We are creating tasks to load data from GCS to big query based on dativize sequentially. Consider
task a(03rd June)>>task b(04th June)>>task c(05th June) .
If task a is failed ,we don't want to put entire flow as failure ,but should skip the failed task and execute the next task.

Can anyone suggest the approach to follow , as we are newbies it would be great if anyone can guide us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the trigger_rule of task_b and task_c to be "ALWAYS"

Comment: How can I manually set up task instance status as skipped , FYI I don't want to use either Bash or python operator